# Use local WiFi directly even when PC is connected to OpenVPN Server

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, openvpn

This is the following setup I currently have on a Windows 10 Pro Machine

- 2 Ethernet Cards
- One Ethernet Card connected to my main router
- Install OpenVPN Client with its virtual TAP adapter and start a new tunnel
- Share the Windows TAP Adapter with Second Ethernet card using Internet Connection Sharing
- This ethernet is plugged in to a LAN port of router acting as an AP

The result is that I have two SSIDs in home. One for accessing my local network & internet using my ISP IP and one for accessing internet via VPN. Windows Internet Connection Sharing provides DHCP for the VPN WiFi locally.

At this moment, I cannot use this PC for browsing local network without disconnecting the OpenVPN client as all browsing data is routed through the VPN.

**Is there any way I can have OpenVPN TAP adapter only use traffic coming from 
2nd ethernet and still use my 1st ethernet for all my local surfing?**

Comment: Are you using Windows? I'm sure there is a way w/ Linux!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Yes, this is on a Windows 10 Pro Machine. Update the post to reflect this